# Hide one of the ImageView in UITableViewCell>

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my application I am displaying images coming from backend in tableViewCell.
My tableViewCell has two imageViews with aspect ratio set to each image.
Depending on web service response I need to display that images in UITableViewCell.
Assume that two images are coming from backend I am displaying both the images.
But when only one image is coming from backend I am hiding that image by making its aspectRatio isActive property to the NO.

Image is getting hide but aspectRatio of second image is not working properly, it displays stretched image which is wrong.

I am using UITableViewAutomaticDimesion property of UITableView for row height.

Comment: If image is displayed as stretched, You need to look at contentMode property and not at constraints. You should use .aspectFit or .aspectFill according to your requirement.

Comment: Is there any issue when you receive both the images and you show them both ?

Comment: I have already set AspectRatio Property for it. Then image would be adjust according to aspcetRatio.

Comment: @HemantSabale i think you have to check my answer so you got idea about it

Comment: Sharing code might help.

Comment: I have solved it. Issue is due to initially isActive property set No for imageView aspectRatio and I am not changed it to Yes one images received from backend. Because of which this problem happen.